# Find the highest product in 4 directions in a matrix

Tags: php, algorithm, matrix

I got this challenge to find the highest product of 4 consecutive numbers on a `20x20 matrix of integers`.

The numbers are read line by line from a file separated by a space.

The products can be in horizontal, vertical and diagonal in both directions

My "solution" gives the wrong answer.

**EDIT**: I've updated the code to work without file input and added sample data; also fixed one of my mistakes that were pointed out in the comments

```
$data = [
    [89,32,92,64,81,2,20,33,44,1,70,75,39,62,76,35,16,77,22,27],
    [53,11,6,95,41,51,31,59,8,23,19,13,61,91,48,69,84,52,66,24],
    [93,72,85,97,21,79,56,5,45,3,65,30,83,87,43,7,34,0,4,14],
    [29,17,49,9,82,90,55,67,15,63,54,94,12,28,96,37,58,98,86,78],
    [74,40,50,60,26,99,80,18,10,46,36,68,25,57,47,71,42,73,88,38],
    [50,22,6,26,18,53,52,5,46,2,89,77,83,48,4,58,45,28,84,81],
    [49,82,31,14,69,17,91,54,34,40,0,33,30,95,60,44,29,24,85,16],
    [27,11,76,39,15,86,92,74,99,59,94,12,55,57,38,96,47,32,78,75],
    [51,20,87,42,62,41,7,35,23,21,71,25,67,97,80,90,88,64,13,70],
    [19,9,56,43,68,93,65,98,36,3,61,63,10,72,8,73,1,66,79,37],
    [22,58,52,12,3,41,28,72,42,74,76,64,59,35,85,78,14,27,53,88],
    [46,80,5,96,7,68,61,69,67,34,36,40,82,26,75,50,29,91,10,2],
    [30,39,19,48,33,93,1,45,66,98,0,23,62,25,51,71,56,77,24,21],
    [79,87,94,60,8,32,13,65,4,92,73,9,31,37,17,84,15,90,86,20],
    [95,6,81,70,47,16,44,83,49,43,55,54,18,63,38,11,97,89,99,57],
    [95,78,64,58,7,17,53,28,74,86,6,12,54,85,21,94,16,69,25,68],
    [13,20,41,97,1,2,80,30,0,84,67,45,93,96,82,92,62,33,18,44],
    [60,77,31,70,76,36,59,38,15,3,91,46,65,73,49,11,8,35,5,52],
    [61,66,79,40,26,72,89,71,75,99,22,9,43,32,14,81,98,88,87,83],
    [10,4,23,19,56,57,51,47,50,27,90,63,42,29,24,55,48,37,39,34]
];

$matrix = [];
//maximums in possible directions
$maxes  = [0, 0, 0, 0];

//while ($line = trim(fgets(STDIN))) { 
while ($line = current($data)) {
    //the horizontal maxes can be calculated while loading
    //$array = explode(" ", $line);
    $array = $line;

    $hMax = array_product(array_slice($array, 0, 4));

    for ($i = 1; $i < (count($array)-4); $i++) {
        $max = array_product(array_slice($array, $i, 4));

        if($max > $hMax) {
            $hMax = $max;
        }
    }

    if ( $hMax > $maxes[0] ) {
        $maxes[0] = $hMax;
    }

    $matrix[] = $array;
    next($data);
}

// the last 3 rows can be skipped
for($i = 0; $i < (count($matrix)-4); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < (count($matrix[$i])-1); $j++) {

        $vMax  = 1;   // vertical
        $dlMax = 1;   // diagonal left
        $drMax = 1;   // diagonal rigth

        for ($k = 0; $k < 5; $k++) {
            $vMax  *= $matrix[$i + $k][$j];

            if ( $j < (count($matrix[$i]) - 4) ) {
                $drMax *= $matrix[$i + $k][$j + $k];
            }

            if ( $j > 3 ) {
                $dlMax *= $matrix[$i + $k][$j - $k];
            }
        }

        if ( $maxes[1] < $vMax )  $maxes[1] = $vMax;  // the index used to be 1 - my first mistake
        if ( $maxes[2] < $dlMax ) $maxes[2] = $dlMax; // the index used to be 1 - my first mistake
        if ( $maxes[3] < $drMax ) $maxes[3] = $drMax; // the index used to be 1 - my first mistake
    }
}

sort($maxes);
echo end($maxes).PHP_EOL;
```

Where did my approach go wrong, and how can it be sped up?
Are there any math tricks that can be applied here `(besides checking for zeros)?`

**EDIT**: the solution that the code gives for the current data is `4912231320` is it correct?

Comment: I'm not convinced that you're checking every possible vertical and diagonal product. But there's definitely a problem with the way the `maxes` are being updated. You're only updating `maxes[1]`.

Comment: I1m skipping the last 3 rows of the matrix, because the vertical and diagonals will count forwards 3 rows anyways (see ` for $k`)

Comment: All the numbers are less than 100. So the maximum possible product is `99*99*99*99 = 96059601`. I suggest making a 6x6 matrix (with every element unique) and then print the 4 numbers for every product. With a 6x6 matrix, there should be 18 horizontal products, 18 vertical products, and 9 products for each of the diagonals.

Answer (score 1):

I've found 2 major errors, and now the result is a plausible `67352832`

I'm considering it solved for that reason, but if anyone comes up with some math trick that simplifies or makes it faster I'll give up the accepted answer.

The first mistake was 
`for ($k = 0; $k < 5; $k++) {`

It should've been
`for ($k = 0; $k < 4; $k++) {`

since we are only counting 4 numbers at once, thats why the result was so large compared to 10^8

The second was
`if ( $j > 3 ) {`

which should've been
`if ( $j > 2 ) {`

which will now include one more diagonal possibility

Answer (score 1):

We can consider the four directions a bottom- or right-most cell can be the last of in a sequence. If `m[i][j][k][d]` is the highest total for a sequence of length `k` coming from direction `d`, then:

```
m[i][j][1][d] = data[i][j] for all d

m[i][j][k]['E'] = data[i][j] * m[i][j - 1][k - 1]['E']
m[i][j][k]['NE'] = data[i][j] * m[i - 1][j - 1][k - 1]['NE']
m[i][j][k]['N'] = data[i][j] * m[i - 1][j][k - 1]['N']
m[i][j][k]['NW'] = data[i][j] * m[i - 1][j + 1][k - 1]['NW']
```

If we traverse north to south, east to west, the needed cells should have already been calculated, and, clearly, we're looking for

```
max(m[i][j][4][d])
  for all i, j, d
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, than I need to go through the whole dataset, there are no shortcuts ?

Comment: @zedling how could we skip a cell? What if that cell was a 2 in a matrix where all other cells were 1?